# Whats is the correct format to works with arrays in a json file to insert in bigquery?

Tags: arrays, json, google-bigquery

I`m trying to insert a json file like this one at bigquery, but bigquery doesn't accept this JSON format.

```
{
    "id": "0000",
    "sub_id": "00",
    "price": "0.0",
    "status": "delivered",
    "capture_method": "ecommerce",
    "payment_method": "credit",
    "timestamp": "2020-09-13T17:35:33.841583",
    "buyer": "Joe Due",
    "asset": "brl",
    "metadata": {
        "data": {
            "order_info": {
                "order_number": null,
                "order_name": null,
                "package_name": null
            }
        },
        "data_xxx": null,
        "data_xxxxx": null
              ...

    },
    "source": "1"
}
```

This error keep appearing "Error while reading data, error message: Failed to parse JSON: Unexpected end of string; Unexpected end of string; Expected key"...

I`m using Apache Beam with DataFlow to do this insert.

```
   with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
  mobile_data = (
      pipeline
      | 'ReadJSON' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(path)
      | 'ParseJSON' >> beam.Map(json.loads)
      | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery('{0}:my_dataset.my_table'.format('my-project'),
    schema=table_schema, write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
```

A Sample Output:

```
{'id': '000', 'sub_id': '000', 'price': '0.0', 'status': 'delivered', 'provider': 'xxxx', 'capture_method': 'ecommerce', 'payment_method': 'credit', 'created_at': '2020-09-13T17:35:33.841583', 'updated_at': '2020-09-13T17:35:38.550684', 'xxx': 'xxxx', 'xxx_number': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxx_xxx_name': 'Joe Due', 'xxx': '1', 'asset': 'brl', 'metadata': {'data': {'xxx_info': {'version': None, 'xxx': None, 'xxx': None, 'package_name': None}, 'xxx_info': {'model': None, 'sensors': {'gyroscope_events': [{'x': None, 'y': None, 'z': None}, {'x': None, 'y': None, 'z': None}, {'x': None, 'y': None, 'z': None}, {'x': None, 'y': None, 'z': None}, {'x': None, 'y': None, 'z': None}], 'xxx': [{'x': None, 'y': None, 'z': None}, {'x': None, 'y': None, 'z': None}, {'x': None, 'y': None, 'z': None}, {'x': None, 'y': None, 'z': None}, {'x': None, 'y': None, 'z': None}], 'xxx': [{'x': None, 'y': None, 'z': None}, {'x': None, 'y': None, 'z': None}, {'x': None, 'y': None, 'z': None}, {'x': None, 'y': None, 'z': None}, {'x': None, 'y': None, 'z': None}]}, 'xxx': None, 'xxx': None, 'xxxx': [{'xxx': None, 'xxx': None, 'xxx': None, 'xxx': None, 'xxx': None}, {'xxx': None, 'xxx': None, 'xx': None, 'xxx': None, 'xx': None}, {'xxx': None, 'xxx': None, 'xxx': None, 'xxx': None, 'xx': None}, {'xx': None, 'heading': None, 'xx': None, 'xxx': None, 'xxx': None}, {'xx': None, 'xx': None, 'xx': None, 'xx': None, 'xxx': None}], 'xxx': {'xxx': None, 'xx': None, 'level': None}, 'xx': None, 'xxx': None, 'xxx': None}}, 'xxx': None, 'xxxx': None}, 'xxx': 'xx', 'source': '1'}
```

I think that output is too long, so cannot be on a single line, Bigquery just accepts Newline delimited JSON (ndjson).

Does anyone have an idea to parse this JSON file?

Comment: Could you share the Apache Beam code you are using to insert?

Comment: @Thomas i put my apache beam code at post, thanks for help

Comment: Hi @Lucas, is the input file formatted json or newline delimited json?

Comment: So Apache Beam is a system you use for paralel data processing, ReadFromText actually parses the input file line for line and on each line you are performing the json.loads operation. Thats why you get the Expected Key error.